# Partial not rendered via RJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my new.html.erb page, i use the following line to render a partial and it works fine.

```
<%= render :partial => "submissions/player_form", :locals => { :submission => @submission }  %>
```

Now i want to render exactly the same partial via RJS

```
<p>Player Type: <%= f.select(:PLAYER_TYPE, $playersList, {:prompt => 'Select the Player Type'} %></p>


<%= observe_field("submission_PLAYER_TYPE", :frequency => 1,
                                               :url => { :controller => 'submissions',
                                               :action => :display_player_form },
                                                :with => "'player='+value") %>
```

**display_player_form.rjs:**

```
  page.replace_html 'observed_assay_form', :partial => 'submissions/player_form', :locals => {:submission => @submission }
```

Nothing is displayed!!

Am i missing something??

Thanks for helping me out with this :)

Comment: Dose it work if you use an insert_html call in RJS? `page.insert_html :bottom,:partial => 'submissions/player_form', :locals => {:submission => @submission }`

Comment: Are there any errors in the JS console?

Comment: no, am not getting any error message

Comment: Can you try triggering anything from the RJS? It dosnt sound like its being run.

Comment: in my partial, if i remove the contents of the form--that is '<% form_for @submission do |f| %>' ...<%end%> and put some text, the partial is rendered without any problem.

Comment: I feel the problem lies with rendering a form, although i did pass the variable via ':locals => {:submission => @submission }' in the rjs code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. So here are my findings:

1. In the partial, include the form_for tag, just like in the original form--

   <% form_for @object do |f| %>
2. In the action used when observing the field, in my case, 'display_player_form', create a new instance of the object(see below)

   @object = Object.new
3. In your rjs file, enter the following:

   page['id of div'].replace_html :partial => 'your_partial_name'

There you go...

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would rename display_player_form.rjs to display_player_form.js.erb and have its contents look like this:

```
$("#observed_essay_form").html('<%=
  escape_javascript(
    render :partial => 'submissions/player_form', :locals => {:submission => @submission }
  )
-%>');
$("img[src$='spinner.gif']:visible").hide(); // optional - hide any visible spinner.gif images
```

I use jQuery, not Prototype, by the way.

Comment: I am getting an error...is that because am using rails 2.3.5?

Comment: No, that wouldn't be the reason.  I would run Firebug in Firefox to inspect the HTTP request (make sure it is an AJAX request) and to check the HTTP response (make sure it looks OK and doesn't have an error message).